# I'm new to java programming and I am trying to use Java docs but I am completely lost

Tags: java

This may sound really silly but there is a whole documentation of the libraries and classes in java and I am trying to learn how to use this to write programs since I don't want to refer to someone else code but I was completlely lost when I look at the documentation online: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Can someone please help me understand how i can use this?

Comment: The documentation is more of a dictionary / encyclopedia than a tutorial. For help learning a language, consult tutorials. You can't build a car just by looking at a parts list. What's your aversion to referring to others' code?

Comment: adding more info,you are looking at dictionary, look in to grammatical book.

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? It's a decent question for new coders who know nothing. Is that not part of Stackoverflow's purpose; to create a database of **useful** questions and answers that will help out coders of all skill levels?

Comment: I wonder if that semicolon is in the right place...

Comment: You shouldn't fear looking at other people's code. You can learn a ton of things from someone else's code. Especially if they are better than you at Java. They know and can teach you all kinds of things that you'll take a lot longer to learn by yourself. There is a difference here though. I, personally, don't believe copying someone else's code word for word will teach you anything. However, taking a section of their code, and using it to do something completely different is like killing two birds with one stone because you learn two different ways to implement the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to go up one level and look at tutorials first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. Once you understand the basics of Java, then you can use the API reference to find the classes and methods you need.